# TFS 2010 RC TeamBuild - Unable to view Test Run Results

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Using Visual Studio & TFS 2010 RC TeamBuild, I get a message "Unable to view Test Run Results" when I click to View Test Results of my build in Team Explorer.

The trx file exists on the server and Ive tried giving full permissions to the containing folder.

The Build Log file says the tests were run (some failed) and published successfully. Ive included an excerpt below ...

```
Summary
-------
Test Run Failed.
Passed  38
Failed  46
----------
Total   84
Results file:  d:\Builds\1\XXXlWeb\XXXlWeb\TestResults\MYSERVER$_MYSERVER 2010-02-18 11_48_10_Mixed Platforms_Debug.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings
Waiting to publish...
Publishing results of test run MYSERVER$@MYSERVER 2010-02-18 11:48:10_Mixed Platforms_Debug to http://myserver:8080/tfs/ABCCollection...
..Publish completed successfully.

00:00
Handle MSTest Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very strange. Im not aware of anything changing, but today it's just started working! Not going to worry about it as it works now :)